# How can i get from the List<string> of files each time another file?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The code:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\coneimages", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".mp3") || s.EndsWith(".gif"));
    foreach (string f in files)
    {
        filesl.Add(f);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < filesl.Count; i++)
    {
        Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(filesl[i]);
        Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(@"c:\coneimages\PictureBox_Images1.gif");
        Bitmap bmp3 = new Bitmap(GenerateImage(bmp2, bmp1));
        bmp3.Save(@"c:\coneimages\merged.bmp");
    }
```

files is `IEnumerable<string>` and `filesl` is `List<string>`

The problem is here: `Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(filesl[i]);`

Before it was like this: `Bitmap bmp1 = Bitmap(@"c:\coneimages\Cone_Images1.gif");`

The problem is that i have many files in the `List<string>`

First in the List i have all th Cone_images files for example:

`Cone_images1,Con_images2,Con_images3......Con_images360`

Then in the same List after i have:

`PictureBox_Images1,PictureBox_Images2....PictureBox_Images360`

In the loop what i need to do is to take each itertion two files and merge them.
For example the files: `Con_images1 with PictureBox_Images1`
Next itertion in the loop next couple of files: `Con_images2 with PictureBox_Images2` .....the last itertion will be: `Con_images360 with PictureBox_Images360`

Comment: Why are you adding your result file list to anthor list you can just apply the `.ToList()` to convert it to list.

Comment: What is your problem now :)

Comment: Why do you need mp3 files too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the filename for the one type starts always with `"Cone_images"` whereas the other always starts with `"PictureBox_Images"` and ends with the numeric part? Then i'd separate them in the first place. Finally you could use `Enumerable.Zip` after you've ordered them by the number-part:

```
var allFiles =Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\coneimages", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".mp3") || s.EndsWith(".gif"));
var coneFiles = allFiles
    .Where(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f).StartsWith("Cone_images", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    .Select(f => new
    {
        File = f,
        NumberPart = String.Concat(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f).SkipWhile(c => !char.IsDigit(c)).TakeWhile(char.IsDigit))
    }).Where(x => x.NumberPart.Any())
    .Select(x => new { x.File, Number = int.Parse(x.NumberPart) })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Number);
var pictureBoxFiles = allFiles
     .Where(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f).StartsWith("PictureBox_Images", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    .Select(f => new
    {
        File = f,
        NumberPart = String.Concat(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f).SkipWhile(c => !char.IsDigit(c)).TakeWhile(char.IsDigit))
    }).Where(x => x.NumberPart.Any())
    .Select(x => new { x.File, Number = int.Parse(x.NumberPart) })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Number);

var bothFileTypes = coneFiles.Zip(pictureBoxFiles, (cone, pic) => new { cone, pic });
foreach (var xy in bothFileTypes)
{
    Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(xy.cone.File);
    Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(xy.pic.File);
    Bitmap bmp3 = new Bitmap(GenerateImage(bmp2, bmp1));
    bmp3.Save(@"c:\coneimages\merged.bmp");
}
```

---

Here is another approach similar to Sayse's using `Enumerable.GroupBy`. It does not rely on the order and doesn't zip files which possibly don't belong together. It groups by the number at the end and identifies the type of each file:

```
string coneIdentifier = "Cone_images";
string picIdentifier = "PictureBox_Images";
var numberGroups = Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\coneimages", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(f => Path.GetExtension(f).Equals(".mp3", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || Path.GetExtension(f).Equals(".gif", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    .Select(f => new { File = f, FileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f) })
    .Where(x => x.FileName.StartsWith(coneIdentifier, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || x.FileName.StartsWith(picIdentifier, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    .Select(x => new
    {
        x.File,
        x.FileName,
        NumberPart = String.Concat(x.FileName.SkipWhile(c => !char.IsDigit(c)).TakeWhile(char.IsDigit)),
        Type = String.Concat(x.FileName.TakeWhile(c => !char.IsDigit(c)))
    })
    .Where(x => x.NumberPart.Length > 0 && x.Type.Length > 0)
    .GroupBy(x => x.NumberPart);

foreach (var grp in numberGroups)
{
    var cone = grp.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type.Equals(coneIdentifier, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
    var pic = grp.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type.Equals(picIdentifier, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
    if (cone == null || pic == null) continue;
    Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(cone.File);
    Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(pic.File);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I really think he needs merged1.bmp, merged2.bmp etc

Comment: @AdrianIftode: but he wrote: _"For example the files: Con_images1 with PictureBox_Images1 Next itertion in the loop next couple of files: Con_images2 with PictureBox_Images2"_ So the number determines the pair.

Comment: Yes, but merged.bmp wouldn't be only Con_imagesN with PictureBox_ImagesN?

Comment: so probably he needs something like bmp3.Save(string.Format(@"c:\coneimages\merged{0}.bmp",xy.cone.Number));

Comment: @AdrianIftode: i don't know his business logic or what `GenerateImage` does, i thought that the algorithm to merge the pairs was the core issue of this question. I'm waiting for feedback from OP.

Comment: Tim i added to my question the GenerateImage method code. And in your solution it's never get in to the foreach loop. I couldn't find why it dosen't give any exception just pass over the foreach loop.

Comment: Tim i added to my question the GenerateImage method code. And in your solution it's never get in to the foreach loop. I couldn't find why it dosen't give any exception just pass over the foreach loop.

Comment: Any another thing the saved bmp in the loop the bmp3 should be each itertion another file not the same merged.bmp but once merged.bmp next itertion merged.bmp1 next merged.bmp2 and so on. each two bmp2 and bmp1 should give a new merged bmp.

Comment: @HelemShoshi: check it again. I have changed `SkipWhile(char.IsLetter).TakeWhile(char.IsDigit)` to `SkipWhile(c => !char.IsDigit(c)).TakeWhile(char.IsDigit)`. I think that the underscore in `Cone_images` is not a letter which breaks the query.

Comment: @HelemShoshi: i have also provided another approach which is safer since it only groups pairs by their number instead of their order.

Comment: I found that it never get into the line part: File = f of the PictureBox_Images but it does for the Cone_Images coyld be the problem is that the PictureBox_Images are Images i saved from the pictureBox1 and the Con_Images are Bitmaps ?

Comment: @HelemShoshi: you cannot debug that line since it's a LINQ query so i wonder why it "does for the Cone_Images". Have you used the new code?

Comment: @HelemShoshi - if the file names are prefixed with pictureBox**1** it will make a big difference as to how this solution would work for you... your original question states that the filenames start with "pictureBox_Images" is this correct?

Comment: Sayse maybe the problem is with the StartsWith ? In the List files i see first the first 360 files are: C:\coneimages\Cone_Images10.gif start with coneimages but then after 360 files the next 360 files are: C:\coneimages\PictureBox_Images26.gif it's still coneimages maybe StartsWith meaning the beginning of the string not the file name ?

Comment: @HelemShoshi: no, `FileName` is extracted from the ful path with `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f)` which returns only `PictureBox_Images26` and the file-name starts with `PictureBox_Images`.

Comment: Tim i just saw now the edited and the second approach and the second approach is working. Thank you.

Comment: @HelemShoshi: i have not only added that approach but also edited my first. But i have mentioned that in my comments above. I'm glad to hear that it works now.

Comment: Tim one more question please: On the hard disk the images are numbered as 1 2 3 4 5....360 for cone images and same for picturebix images. But in the code the images are not ordered not sorted like they are on the hard disk 1 2 3 4...So in the end i get merged images that are not the same couples. Some times it's merging Cone_Images53 with PictureBox_Images121 how can i sort them ?

Comment: @HelemShoshi: that is not possible with the second approach because it doesn't rely on the order. It groups by the number part so that `Cone_Images53` is in the same group as `PictureBox_Images53`. So `numberGroups` contains groups with unique numbers as key and normally two files, one with `Type="Cone_images"` and one with `Type="PictureBox_Images"`. The grouping is also the reason why this approach does not need to order. Use the debugger in the `foreach`-loop.

Answer (score 0):

if the naming of your Cone_images & PictureBox is always the same, this may help:

```
Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(filesl[i]);
string filePictureBox = string.Format(@"c:\coneimages\PictureBox_Images{0}.gif", i);

// check if file exists
if(File.Exists(filePictureBox))
{
    Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(filePictureBox);
    Bitmap bmp3 = new Bitmap(GenerateImage(bmp2, bmp1));
    bmp3.Save(@"c:\coneimages\merged.bmp");
}
```